# How to turn on camera flash in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera

I am building an app where you users can upload their videos to firebase. I am using the camera package for the camera module. I want to turn on the flash when the user clicks on the flash icon or turn it off.

I tried to find a way to turn on the flash through the camera package but I couldn't find any way to open up the flash.Then, I tried using the lamp package but for some reason the flash is not opening.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:lamp/lamp.dart';

enum FlashState { Flash_OFF, Flash_On, Flash_Auto }

class CameraView extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];
  CameraView() {
    availableCameras().then((cams) {
      cameras.addAll(cams);
      print(cameras.length);
      print(cams.toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  _CameraViewState createState() => _CameraViewState();
}

class _CameraViewState extends State<CameraView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  CameraController _controller;
  int _selectedCameraIndex;
  bool _isRecording;

  FlashState currentFlashState = FlashState.Flash_OFF;
  String flashIcon = 'flash-off';

  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _colorTween;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: Colors.blueGrey, end: Colors.red)
        .animate(_animationController);
    // _controller = CameraController(widget.cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high,
    //     enableAudio: true);
    // _isRecording = false;
    // _controller.initialize().then((_) {
    //   if (!mounted) {
    //     return;
    //   }
    //   setState(() {});
    // });
    if (widget.cameras.length > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedCameraIndex = 0;
      });
      _switchCamera(widget.cameras[_selectedCameraIndex]);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _startVideoRecording(BuildContext context) async {
    if (!_controller.value.isInitialized) {
      await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Camera Not Responding.'),
              content: Center(
                child: Text('Something went wrong.Try Again Later.'),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Okay.'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
      return null;
    }
    if (_controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return null;
    }
    setState(() {
      _isRecording = true;
    });
    final Directory appDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String videoDirectory = '${appDirectory.path}/Videos';
    await Directory(videoDirectory).create(recursive: true);
    final String currentTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    final String filePath = '$videoDirectory/$currentTime.mp4';

    try {
      //Lamp.turnOn();
      await _controller.startVideoRecording(filePath);
      //Lamp.turnOff();
      StorageReference firebaseStorageReference =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(basename(filePath));
      StorageUploadTask videoUploadTask = firebaseStorageReference.putFile(
        File(filePath),
        StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'),
      );
      StorageTaskSnapshot uploadSnapshot = await videoUploadTask.onComplete;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _stopVideoRecording() async {
    if (!_controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await _controller.stopVideoRecording();
      setState(() {
        _isRecording = false;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _switchCamera(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (_controller != null) {
      await _controller.dispose();
    }
    _controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
      if (_controller.value.hasError) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'An Error Occured',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIos: 2,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black38);
      }
    });
    try {
      await _controller.initialize();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _onSwitchCamera() {
    _selectedCameraIndex = _selectedCameraIndex < widget.cameras.length - 1
        ? _selectedCameraIndex + 1
        : 0;
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = widget.cameras[_selectedCameraIndex];
    _switchCamera(selectedCamera);
    setState(() {
      _selectedCameraIndex = _selectedCameraIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _controller.value.isInitialized
        ? Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: CameraPreview(_controller),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.40,
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                child: AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: _colorTween,
                  builder: (context, child) => IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      MaterialCommunityIcons.getIconData('video'),
                    ),
                    color: _colorTween.value,
                    iconSize: 80.0,
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (!_isRecording) {
                        _animationController.forward();
                        _startVideoRecording(context);
                      } else if (_isRecording) {
                        _animationController.reverse();
                        _stopVideoRecording();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 22.0,
                top: 22.0,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    MaterialCommunityIcons.getIconData('camera-switch'),
                  ),
                  onPressed: _onSwitchCamera,
                  iconSize: 28.0,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 22.0,
                top: 22.0,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    MaterialCommunityIcons.getIconData(flashIcon),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    currentFlashState =
                        currentFlashState.index < FlashState.values.length - 1
                            ? FlashState.values[currentFlashState.index + 1]
                            : FlashState.values[0];
                            if(currentFlashState == FlashState.Flash_On){
                              setState(() {
                                flashIcon = 'flash';
                              });
                              //Lamp.turnOn(); Turning on the flash through lamp package flutter but the flash not opening 
                            } else if(currentFlashState == FlashState.Flash_Auto){
                              setState(() {
                                flashIcon = 'flash-auto';
                              });
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                flashIcon = 'flash-off';
                              });
                              //Lamp.turnOff(); 
                            }
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        : Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Loading'),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: I have checked following packages for flash feature in flutter but none of them is working: flutter_flashlight, flutter_lantern, torch_compat, faro_torch

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to recent update on camera: **^0.8.0**.
You can use your camera flash manually:

Step-1:
First follow this whole camera instructions:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera

Step-2:
Then create any button, and on its onPressed function, just write this line.

```
//**For Flash OFF**:

 ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
            },
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.transparent),
            child: Text(
              "Flash Off",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
            ),
          ),


 // **For Flash ON**
     ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.always);
            },
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.transparent),
            child: Text(
              "Flash On",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
            ),
          )
 //**For AUTO Flash:**
  ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.auto);
            },
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.transparent),
            child: Text(
              "Auto Flash",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 3):

Right now there's no camera plugin that accepts the use of flash. One workaround people are using is use this package https://pub.dev/packages/lamp to turn on the phone lamp before taking a photo and turning off afterwards.

It's not the ideal solution, but right now is the best one available

Comment: I have tried this but the flash is not turning on for some reason.

Comment: @ArbazIrshad you're right. it only works on iOS which makes it kind of useless :(

Answer (score 3):

Asim Zubairs answer is correct, for flutter camera plugin, it's good to highlight that `FlashMode.always` is turning on flashlight only while capturing the photo, but if you want to turn on the flashlight and keep it, for situations like video recording, `FlashMode.torch` will work for that.

Here is the FlashMode enum from the camera plugin

```
enum FlashMode {
  /// Do not use the flash when taking a picture.
  off,

  /// Let the device decide whether to flash the camera when taking a picture.
  auto,

  /// Always use the flash when taking a picture.
  always,

  /// Turns on the flash light and keeps it on until switched off.
  torch,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried `camera:^0.10.5+2` and tried to implement the suggestions here but it didn't work. After some time of research, I found a way to turn on the flashlight using `FlashMode.torch`.

Like this: `_cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.torch);`

**Note**:
I use a POCO phone.